# angularjs 1.5 / laravel bad request 400

Tags: angularjs, api, laravel

When I do a POST request using my angular app to my laravel api I get an error bad request 400 , however GET requests work normally, also I do POST requests using POSTMAN and it works , here is my code :

```
$http.get('http://localhost/laravel/datingApp/jobapi/public/api/user/users');
```

this get request works, this post request doesn't (data is an js object {'email': 'value','password': 'value'}) :

```
  $http({

            url: 'http://localhost/laravel/datingApp/jobapi/public/api/user/login',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: data

  }).success(function(data) {

            console.log(data);

  });
```

also I tried doing that just regular way: `$http.post('blabla');` but it doesn't work either :(

edit: sorry didn't include error:

```
angular.js:12011 POST   
http://localhost/laravel/datingApp/jobapi/public/api/user/login 400 (Bad Request)

(anonymous function)          @ angular.js:12011
sendReq                       @ angular.js:11776
serverRequest                 @ angular.js:11571
processQueue                  @ angular.js:16383
(anonymous function)          @ angular.js:16399
$eval                         @ angular.js:17682
$digest                       @ angular.js:17495
$apply                        @ angular.js:17790
(anonymous function)          @ angular.js:25890
dispatch                      @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle                      @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: Could you give more information about the error you get? How did you define {data} and why did you put curly brackets around it?

Comment: need to see the exact error

Comment: sorry, I have added the error code , @piscator data is a js object {'email' : value, 'password' : value} , its a typo that I added it in {} it should be just data

Comment: Perhaps the json isn't valid (you can check this with an online parser), or the server isn't expecting json but form data?

Comment: I tried without any data at all and I still get the error , even I did a brand new installation of angular and still same

Comment: can you use error listener on the request and print the response on console ?

Comment: What is error listener? I have posted the error from chrome console

Comment: jaysingkar means to add an error(function(error, status)) method to your http call to log the error (see docs). In addition, you can use the network tab in the chrome inspector (chrome console) to record the network log. This will show the response from the server.

Comment: thanks @piscator, I found the error using error(function(error, status)) , stupid mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a stupid error, but thanks to @piscator I have found it, Laravel by default returns 400 when validation rules are not met , So my input was wrong all the time that is the reason I got 400.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the post request is working via postman, it seems that when your angular app does an post request it gets stuck due to browser CORS policy.

You need to have a access-control-allow-origin present in the header of the response for the post requests to works.

Comment: angular is on the same domain with the api + I have                                       `  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` in my middleware CORS in Laravel api